# Is there a difference between 물결 and 파도?

Tags: vocabulary, word-choice, word-usage

I understand them both as `wave`, but I'm not sure if there's a difference in nuance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

파도 is the big wave you see in the sea (or some very large lakes, but Korea doesn't have any such lakes).  물결 is small waves you can see anywhere (say, a pond, river, or even your bathtub).

See this example [describing the Five Great Lakes](https://namu.wiki/w/%EC%98%A4%EB%8C%80%ED%98%B8) of the US:

> 호수라고 부르고 있지만 워낙 커서 사진으로 보거나 실제로 가 보면 수평선이 펼쳐져 있고 **파도**도 치는 모습이라 그냥 보면 바다처럼 보인다.

Also note that "wave" in physics is called 파동.

Comment: Great example sentence!